# When and where should I connect and disconnect Mongoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to Mongonengine and I'm using it in a Django project. As the [documents](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html) say, I should first make a connection using `connect` method. My question is that where should this be done?

Also there is a `disconnect` method, I'm wondering whether I should use it and if yes, where should I use it?

I mean should I connect in a separate file Or every time I want to query the database I should open a connection and then close it?

Comment: I think it is settings.py

Comment: I do too, but 2 questions: 1. When to disconnect? 2. Why in `settings.py`

Answer (score -1):

You should connect() mongoengine at the application startup (e.g for flask this is usually when you create the `app = Flask()` application) and then you can forget about it and you don't need to worry about disconnecting it.